# Executing java file in terminal Linux

Tags: java, linux, jsp, sockets, jakarta-ee

i wrote one simple socket program and executing in linux Terminal, while compiling I am not facing any errors , but while running its giving following error..

```
/root/Desktop/httpcore.jar: line 1: PK: command not found
/root/Desktop/httpcore.jar: line 2: 6��:: command not found
/root/Desktop/httpcore.jar: line 22: Ġ�:org/PK: No such file or directory
/root/Desktop/httpcore.jar: line 23: Ġ�:
                                        org/apache/PK: No such file or directory
/root/Desktop/httpcore.jar: line 24: Ǡ�:org/apache/http/PK: No such file or directory
/root/Desktop/httpcore.jar: line 25: Ǡ�:org/apache/http/protocol/PK: No such file or directory
/root/Desktop/httpcore.jar: line 26: Ǡ�:org/apache/http/io/PK: No such file or directory
/root/Desktop/httpcore.jar: line 27: Ǡ�:org/apache/http/message/PK: No such file or directory
/root/Desktop/httpcore.jar: line 28: Ǡ�:org/apache/http/entity/PK: No such file or directory
/root/Desktop/httpcore.jar: line 29: Ǡ�:org/apache/http/util/PK: No such file or directory
/root/Desktop/httpcore.jar: line 30: Ǡ�:org/apache/http/params/PK: No such file or directory
/root/Desktop/httpcore.jar: line 31: Ǡ�:org/apache/http/impl/PK: No such file or directory
/root/Desktop/httpcore.jar: line 32: Ǡ�:org/apache/http/impl/io/PK: No such file or directory
/root/Desktop/httpcore.jar: line 33: Ǡ�:org/apache/http/impl/entity/PK: No such file or directory
/root/Desktop/httpcore.jar: command substitution: line 34: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/root/Desktop/httpcore.jar: command substitution: line 38: syntax error: unexpected end of file
/root/Desktop/httpcore.jar: command substitution: line 21: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
/root/Desktop/httpcore.jar: command substitution: line 21: `�R�+'�3=��6�L\�Z���]�^���&�Q�y|x���[�<�'��$�ְ[ ��GZoU�����kM��[���p4IY�������3�ht�qw��3����r�!8����#A^
                      ?P����v��;��Q|�l��p����cl(?jkZ����  Q�9|R���o��R�yH\1=��qtLH�^cBR�s
                    �g��'��
                           N����P�n�*-�p��c4�� (��KҘ#-����1b����ZY�<H��M�?å���>�dą�n'
/root/Desktop/httpcore.jar: line 21:5��:~��ЁMETA-INF/MANIFEST.MF�O�j�0���: No such file or directory
/root/Desktop/httpcore.jar: line 22: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
/root/Desktop/httpcore.jar: line 22: `~J�"K�Q���M�m7n;<x�A�E��z>h#��Z�L���j�De��}���5��i��e�^���f^�˰H5���腍l(�uD>��[_`�FW�Ph���d!����R�+��K:"�7@)AZV�"r7���5wTXBJ���    v?V>f+�k�F/2�DAfm�p�rtT�iǖ���ȏ�x�4��`��YC<�Q\��ь����B�M�(P.���#��PD�a�F"��l��"����4�u<v���R�܀�Ѧb�l�PFEHJ���$t�����mK��r��7K?�����H�p۷���Y��������f&K��TI�H ������9�S��Ֆ   ���T{�\�3�K����Ǘ�z�'s�+B����@��\j}��E޷�4?b1���ϔs�v�3�J���\�2�`�r
                                                 �"���K��Y3�]a;������u�<��j~�Q��1<Q���`&�
               M�>'
```

Comment: How do you run that program? Jars normally don't report lines during execution, so I suspect you're calling some other program with the jar as your parameter. Additionally, did you provide a Manifest.MF with a correct Main-Class entry?

Comment: while running? so not on the startup, but an actual run time problem?

Comment: you need all dependencies of your jar to be present in the classpath

Comment: This looks like you're trying to execute the jar as binary. Run it with `java -jar httpcore.jar`

Comment: Looks like you don't run this with `java` ....

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the text encoding that you have used to write and save your source code and then when compiling the program you could specify the correct encoding style e.g. by adding `-encoding UTF-8` (according to your encoding type).

Reference:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html

Comment: thanks for your answer please check my code below,execute Linux terminal and please tel me what i have to do..

Comment: you have to check the type of encoding you have used to write and save your source code, because by default javac will treat the file as ascii and clearly your code was not written in ascii.